# Remove OneDrive from the context menu

Tags: windows-registry, onedrive, context-menu, windows-11, microsoft

As per title, I would like to remove “Move to OneDrive” from the context menu in Windows 11. The web is full of tutorials to remove it from Windows 10, but with the updates to Windows 11 all the tweaks no longer work. I have tried many .reg files from different sources, with no effect.

**Update**: not the new Windows 11 context menu, but the classic Windows 10 one, restorable by many online tools.
Sample Image:[Contextual menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKoRe.png)

Answer (score 2):

Try this, tested on Windows 11 22621.1344 and OneDrive 23.033.0212.0001.

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Shell Extensions\Blocked]

"{1FA0E654-C9F2-4A1F-9800-B9A75D744B00}"="OneDrive"

The clsid is found from "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.OneDriveSync_23033.212.1.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppxManifest.xml"

Comment: Doesn't work on OneDrive 23.119

Answer (score 0):

> As per title, I would like to remove “Move to OneDrive” from the
> context menu in Windows 11

I have two Windows 11 machines, one with One Drive active, and one with no One Drive.

The context menus in Windows 11 have been made situationally context sensitive and according cannot be changed with registry tweaks. That ability was removed and nixed.

So you have to accept the context menus as they are at this point.

Windows 11 remains still new and remains at this point a work in progress.

But right now, context menus are not very changeable.

If you are not using One Drive, log out of it and after some time logged out, the context may possibly go away.  I do not have the One Drive context on the non-One Drive machine but that was replaced with the Drop Box  context that I do have.

It is also within reason that the added Windows 10 menu to Windows 11 that may try to change registry entries has compromised your native Windows 11 installation.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question, the context menu I'm talking about is the Windows 10 style one, so editable.

Comment: Classic apps may be hampered by the Windows 11 approach.

Comment: @boromyr - Care you provide us a screenshot in that case?  As an avid Windows 11 user I am not sure I know which context menu you are referring to.

Comment: @Ramhound I uploaded a screen